# count the number of values jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

When I navigate to my jQuery DataTable I would like to display how many Users are pending activation. Normally I would use `fnGetData` with (this) however as I am not trying to do this on a click event and I am simply just trying to count the number in the entire table I'm not sure how to do it:

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#example2').dataTable({
            fnInitComplete: function (oSettings, json) {

                //store table data 
                var data = this.fnGetData();

                var pendingCount = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (data[i][5] != null && data[i][5] == '1') {
                        pendingCount++;
                    }
                }
                $(".panel-footer #pending").val(pendingCount);
                //pass count to html
                //alert(pendingCount);
            },
        "sAjaxSource": "AjaxHandler",
        "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "Id" },
                        { "sName": "ProfileId" },
                        { "sName": "Type" },
                        { "sName": "Name" },
                        { "sName": "Email" },
                        { "sName": "PendingActivation" }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: To improve your question please specify what is going wrong with your current solution, e.g. do you get any errors or see other symptoms of failure?

Comment: Done... thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You have some errors in your logic while calculating total count, see the corrected code below:

```
var data = oTable.fnGetData();

var pendingCount = 0;
for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
   if (data[i][5] != null && data[i][5] == '1') { 
       pendingCount++;
   }        
}

//pass count to html
$(".panel-footer #pending").val(pendingCount);
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lap1p073/1/) for demonstration.

Comment: hmm seems to be outputting 0 all the time?

Comment: @KirstyWhite, my example on jsFiddle works for HTML sourced data. If you have Ajax sourced data, you need to put this code in `fnInitComplete` callback.

Comment: @KirstyWhite, see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lap1p073/2/) with `fnInitComplete` which also works. Regarding your update: use `this` instead of `oTable`.

Comment: See updated question not sure if my code is laid out correct for this

Comment: @KirstyWhite, that's because you cannot initialize the table twice with `dataTable()`. Put `fnInitComplete` into the original table definition.

Comment: Forgot to change the values for the data... thanks a million. Works perfectly now!